# Cannot append ng-model with collection form type Symfony2

Tags: angularjs

I'm working with Symfony2 and AngularJs

I've created a form collection with jquery like symfony2 documentation and i've assigned to every input created dynamically the ng-model , but when I submit form the Angularjs Dom don't detect the dynamic ng-model created !!
I've tried $compile and $apply but i've got no result 
please help 
my code :

```
<script>
var $collectionHolder;

// setup an "add a guest" link
var $addGuestLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_guest_link">Add a guest</a>');
var $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>').append($addGuestLink);

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    // Get the ul that holds the collection of guests
    $collectionHolder = $('ul.guests');

    // add a delete link to all of the existing tag form li elements
    $collectionHolder.find('li').each(function () {
        addGuestFormDeleteLink($(this));
    });

    // add the "add a guest" anchor and li to the guests ul
    $collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);

    // count the current form inputs we have (e.g. 2), use that as the new
    // index when inserting a new item (e.g. 2)
    $collectionHolder.data('index', $collectionHolder.find(':input').length);

    $addGuestLink.on('click', function (e) {
        // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
        e.preventDefault();

        // add a new guest form (see next code block)
        addGuestForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
        var $scope = angular.element('#expenseCtrl').scope();

        $scope.apply(angular.element('#expenseCtrl')
                .injector().get('$compile')(addGuestForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi))('$scope'));
    });
});


function addGuestForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi) {
    // Get the data-prototype explained earlier
    var prototype = $collectionHolder.data('prototype');

    // get the new index
    var index = $collectionHolder.data('index');

    // Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to
    // instead be a number based on how many items we have
    var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);

                    $collectionHolder.data('index', $collectionHolder.children().length);

                    // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a guest" link li
                    var $newFormLi = $('<li></li>').append(newForm);
                    $newLinkLi.before($newFormLi);

                    // add a delete link to the new form
                    addGuestFormDeleteLink($newFormLi);
                }

                function addGuestFormDeleteLink($guestFormLi) {
                    var $removeFormA = $('<a href="#">delete this guest</a>');
                    $guestFormLi.append($removeFormA);

                    $removeFormA.on('click', function (e) {
                        // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
                        e.preventDefault();

                        // remove the li for the guest form
                        $guestFormLi.remove();
                    });
                }

      </script>
```

[View the form who i can't submit values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jieFm.png)

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with symfony

Comment: i've success to add dynamic ng-model to DOM when i click the link  but i've failed to delete them from delete link